# Android send mail with PDF file

Tags: android, file, email, pdf, send

I'm trying to send a PDF file that is located in a folder on the device. The file is selected and sent, but it is empty. Where I'm wrong?

```
String inviare = n_fr.getText().toString();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getString(R.string.app_name)+"/"+"Folder_"+anno+"/"+"file_"+inviare+".pdf")); 

            Intent sendEmail= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                   sendEmail.setType("application/pdf");
                   sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, filename);                         
                   sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Invia PDF"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you've enabled the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest
- Check that the `uri` resolves to an actual file, and try logging the file content (`Log.d`) in that block of code, to ensure the file contents are actually readable.

Comment: Your first bullet is incorrect. Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND): "getType() is the MIME type of the data being sent. get*Extra can have either a EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent. If using EXTRA_TEXT, the MIME type should be "text/plain"; otherwise it should be the MIME type of the data in EXTRA_STREAM."

Comment: You are ofcourse right! Thank you for the correct. I have removed the bullet point, but will paraphrase it here for completeness (and because it's an easy mistake to make!). The incorrect advice was: Don't use sendEmail.setType("application/pdf"). The type refers the the type of the email, normally either text or html. You may simply omit that line.